# Integer won't set into JTextField

Tags: java, sqlite, compiler-errors, awt, auto-increment

I'm having problems in my program. Well, here's my code:

```
    JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Add");
    btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) { 
            try{
                String query = "INSERT INTO GuestList (id, Title, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Address, ContactNo, Occupation) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                count++;

                pst.setString(1, String.valueOf(textField.setText(count + "")); //<<--This is my problem
                pst.setString(2, comboBox.getToolTipText());
                pst.setString(3, fNameTextField.getText());
                pst.setString(4, mNameTextField.getText());
                pst.setString(5, lNameTextField.getText());
                pst.setString(6, addressTextPane.getText());
                pst.setString(7, contactNoTextField.getText());
                pst.setString(8, occupationTextField.getText());
                pst.execute();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Saved!");

                pst.close();

            }catch(Exception e){

            }

        }
    });
```

I'm having an auto increment in the line that has a comment in it. It says that "   - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression" and "The method valueOf(Object) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (void)"

What should I do to get rid of these? Can someone help me? Thank you. :)

Comment: Hint: count the number of opening and closing brackets. They better match up. That is exactly what the compiler is telling you ... just read the message! "Insert a )". Do you really need other people to explain that to you?

Comment: That's the primary key in GuestList table.

Comment: Use some IDE with syntax highlighting and/or syntax checker - they show you such simple problems.

Answer (score 1):

for every opening group like this **(** you will need a closing one like that **)**

you have here 3 open and 2 closed....

```
 pst.setString(1, String.valueOf(textField.setText(count + ""));
```

so you are missing one **)**

try:

```
pst.setString(1, String.valueOf(textField.setText(count + "")));
```

Comment: I already doing it. But another problem was found, again. It says, "The method of valueOf(Object) in the type String is not applicable for the arguements (void)." And when I changed it to copyValueOf(), still the same problem.